# Trying to sort out user input error in C

Tags: user-input, scanf

Hiya, I'm trying to make a small loop which presents an error when the user inputs something apart from a float and gives them another opportunity.  Here's what I've got so far.

```
printf("Enter a value for x:   ");
while (scanf("%lf", &x_temp) != 1) {
    printf("ERROR: Input real number\n");
    printf("Enter a value for x:   ");
    scanf("%lf", &x_temp);
}
```

But this just runs through the loop without giving the user another chance to enter another number:

```
user@user-vm:~/Desktop/Exercise_0$ ./a.out 
Enter a value for x:   a
ERROR: Input real number
Enter a value for x:   ERROR: Input real number
Enter a value for x:   ERROR: Input real number
Enter a value for x:   ERROR: Input real number
Enter a value for x:   ERROR: Input real number
Enter a value for x:   ERROR: Input real number
Enter a value for x:   ERROR: Input real number
Enter a value for x:   ERROR: Input real number
Enter a value for x:   ERROR: Input real number
```

Anyone got any ideas? Cheers guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (;;)
{
    printf("Enter a value for x:   ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &x_temp) == 1) 
        break;
    printf("ERROR: Input real number\n");
}
```

Comment: This works but you have to input the value twice for some reason hmmm Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the return value of the second `scanf` call anywhere. So it's probably succeeding, but then you immediately do another `scanf` at the top of the loop, after the input has already been consumed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the behavior is, but it appears you have an extra scanf(). The one that is part of the while condition will repeat each time through the loop. I don't see a need for the second one at the bottom of the loop.